# Proving $a\equiv b \pmod m$ if $a \bmod m = b\bmod m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove that for integers $a, b$ and positive integers $m$, that $a \equiv b\pmod m$ iff $a \bmod m = b\bmod m$

I’m on my tablet currently so I cannot type up my latex well. But I’ve been trying to do a direct proof using the fact that $b=mq+r$. I also tried using propositional logic, since this is a biconditional I tried proving the implications in both directions, but I’m still getting confused

Comment: Uhm, what defintions are you using for equivalence mod $m$ and the mod function? Because this almost seems like a definition to me

Comment: `\pmod{m}` will produce the parenthetical version of the mod operator (you don’t need to add parentheses); `\bmod` will produce the “mod” operator. `\mod` is the worst of the three, as it produces weird spacing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you have no clue how helpful that comment was for me lol thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here are the first steps to get you started.

Let $a,b,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and assume $a \equiv k \pmod{m}$ and $b \equiv k \pmod{m}$. Then, there exist $n_a, n_b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
\begin{split}
a &= m n_a &+ k \\
b &= m n_b &+ k \\
\end{split}
$$
Can you please subtract the two equations?

**HINT 2**

Since $n_a,n_b$ are integers, so is $n_b - n_a$. Note that
$$
a = mn_a+k = m(n_a-n_b) + mn_b + k = m(n_a-n_b) + b.
$$

Comment: Ok so I find that m divides a-b, but my problem is why do we have $b\equiv k \pmod{m}$

Comment: @Lex_i please see the update

Answer (score 1):

Say $a=qm + r$, $0\leq r\lt m$, and $b=pm + s$, $0\leq s\lt m$, so that $a\bmod m = r$ and $b\bmod m = s$. Without loss of generality, say $r\geq s$.

You want to show that $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ if and only if $r=s$. Presumably you know that $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ if and only if $m|a-b$, if and only if $m$ divides $(qm+r)-(pm+s) = (q-p)m + (r-s)$.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = mx + r_1$ and let $b = my + r_2$

Given $a \mod{m} = b\mod{m} \implies r_1 = r_2 = k$ 
$ \implies a = mx + k, b = my + k$ 
$a - b = m(x - y)$ 
$m \mid m(x - y) \implies m \mid (a - b) \implies a \equiv b (\mod{m}) $